# The order of a group of automorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm asked to find the order of the automorphism group of the group $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_4$ and the group $\Bbb Z_4 \times\Bbb Z_4$ using presentations and by showing that $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_4$ is isomorphic to $$\langle a, b : |a| = 2 , |b| = 4 , ab = ba \rangle ,$$
but my problem is in selecting the one to one onto maps from all possible possibilities !

I found that we have 10 possible automorphisms. Am I wrong ?

And similarly for $\Bbb Z_4 \times\Bbb Z_4$ I found 136 possible automorphisms !

Did I arrive the correct answers ?

Comment: What does the first exclamation mark mean?

Comment: Your first example has 4 elements of order 4, and in this example they are all possible images for the generator $b$. There are two elements of order two that are not squares of the first generator, so two possible images for $a$, and the automorphism group has order $4 \times 2 = 8$. Your answer for the second group is also too large.